# Circular reference that can't be shown

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet with a whole lot of formula's in it, about 4000 I think (including conditional formatting). I sent it to a colleague and they said that an error showed. I re-opened it and was served with the following error (in Dutch):

> Er kan geen formule worden berekend door Microsoft Excel. Er is een
> kringverwijzing aanwezig in een geopende werkmap, maar de verwijzingen
> van de kring kunnen niet worden weergegeven. U kunt proberen de
> laatste formule die u hebt ingevoerd te bewerken of deze te
> verwijderen met de opdracht Ongedaan maken.

Which roughly translates to:

> Excel can't calculate a formula because of a circular reference, but it can't be shown.

Now I could ofcourse trim the worksheet piece by piece to narrow down where the circular reference is located. But is there a more efficient way? The built-in circular reference finder is grayed out, so that is not an option. Installing third party tools is also not an option due to strict software control by the IT department.

Comment: See if setting "Enable iterative calculation" helps [link](https://superuser.com/a/1603183/8672).

Comment: perhaps one of those items in formula auditing will help...

Comment: " more efficient way " that comes to my mind : delete half of the worksheet, save, and re-open. If there is no more error... means that the formula lies in those "just deleted" cells.

Comment: @harrymc that appears to have done the trick for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here was to enable limited iterative calculation in
menu *File > Options > Formulas*, where in the section
"Calculation options" is set:

- Check "Enable iterative calculation"
- Set "Maximum iterations:" to `1`
- Click OK.

With this setting, cyclic formulas were now checked.
Setting the maximum to `1` stopped the check for circular calculations
after only one calculation.